# How can I use an if else statement to catch the error of using ping6 to ping a URL without IPv6?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am pinging a series of web URLs using `ping6`. Of course, not all URLs have an IPv6 address so I get the output `unknown host` when I try to ping6 a URL without an IPv6 address. What I would like to do, using an if else statement, is catch this error and echo "This site does not have an IPv6 Address", otherwise send a series of ping6's. Here is what I tried:

```
if [ (ping6 -c 5 $site) = "unknown host" ]; then
     echo "$site does not have an IPv6 Address"
else
     -irrelevant code in context of question-
fi
```

I think the issue in my code is `(ping6 -c 5 $site) = "unknown host"` and this is not working as I intended. What would be a better way of catching this error where the site does not have an IPv6 address. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the condition like this:

```
if [ "$(ping6 -c 5 $site 2>&1)" = "unknown host" ]; then
```

Because:

- Use `$(...)` instead of `(...)`, which is a syntax error here
- Redirect `stderr` of `ping6` to `stdout`, so that it gets captured
- Double-quote `$(...)`, so that its result is a single string, otherwise it will be split by spaces, and `[ ... ]` will fail with the error: `too many arguments`